# clearly length is important - javascript length issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a div if the length of a string from a db call is not 0

So, to test, I'm trying:

```
html += '<div class="item_image"> price '+image.item_price;
```

Which will print within div item_image something like:

```
price $10
```

So, to show a div I want to because the price field is not empty I'm trying:

```
if(image.item_price.length>0){ // price
        html += '<div class="price_holder">'+image.item_price+'</div>';
        } // price
```

But it does not show the div, it's as if it's is not reading the length correctly, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can use `.length` to get the length of a string. Your setup is probably wrong. Could you show us where `image.item_price` is instantiated?

Comment: what do you see when you console.log(image.item_price.length)

Comment: have you tried using 'undefined' instead of length to validate if the property has a value or not? Length depends on how you are instantiating the variable.

Comment: `image.item_price` is probably a number, which doesn't have a `length` property.

Comment: @zzzzBov Wrong but I understand your though process

Comment: @DarrenSweeney, now that I look this over again, I can see you've got the currency attached.

Comment: @zzzzBov No worries, thanks for your time anyway, appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just check as

```
if(image.item_price){ // price
    html += '<div class="price_holder">'+image.item_price+'</div>';
}
```

It will check for `undefined`, `empty string` and `zero value` conditions. [Javascript Truthy and Falsy conditions](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/)

Comment: but how is the $ in front of the prize on the example?

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks, thats exactly it. I did actually try if(image.item_price!='') which worked and is the same but yours is less code. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the css? It can be that you put somewhere .price_holder { display: none }

```
html = '';
if (image.item_price.length > 0) {
    html += '<div class="price_holder">' + image.item_price + '</div>';
}
$('body').append(html); // don't forget to append html to where you want it displayed
```